# Can't create an anaconda environment

Tags: anaconda

I'm creating a virtual environment with conda. I downloaded the files in this repository and tried to create the environment, but every time I got this error[image]
https://github.com/Pierian-Data/Plotly-Dashboards-with-Dash

Comment: I think there should not be a space here `python= 3.6`-> `python=3.6`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, since the issue was essentially a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You type the command in the wrong way. It should be `conda create --name nursingdash python=3.6` --name with two dashes and python=3.6 without spaces. The following [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) should get you started on managing conda environments. It's a cheat sheet with the most common commands. Take care when writing conda commands - It's syntax should be entered exactly as specified or the anaconda prompt doesn't know what you mean (as you've just noticed)